# add a tibble to a second one with an additional modification

Tags: r

I would like to join two tibbles, but not in the standard way. My reproducible example is as follows. I have the following tibbles:

```
> tb1
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   symbol [1]
  symbol  open    tarima   
  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   
 1 A       25.3    59.5
 2 A       27.1    61.7

> tb2
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   symbol [2]
  symbol  open 
  <chr>  <dbl> 
1 B       60.8  
2 B       60.3  
3 CD      32.4  
4 CD      33.6
```

I would like to get the output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   symbol [3]
  symbol  open   tarima   
  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> 
1 A       25.3   59.5
2 A       27.1   61.7
3 B       60.8   59.5  
4 B       60.3   61.7
5 CD      32.4   59.5  
6 CD      33.6   61.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may first `rbind` the matching columns and then add the other one with recycling:

```
cbind(rbind(tb1[-3], tb2), tb1["tarima"])
#    symbol open tarima
# 1       A 25.3   59.5
# 2       A 27.1   61.7
# 11      B 60.8   59.5
# 21      B 60.3   61.7
# 3      CD 32.4   59.5
# 4      CD 33.6   61.7
```